# Head command in windows

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to excute simple head command in windows in order to find the first folder, something like:
dir /b /a-d | head -1

I can not download addtional kit to this machine and also can't use PowerShell or other script languages.

Comment: In that case you can't.

Comment: @Seth Yes, you can

Comment: @Shaked see my answer

Answer (score 2):

A `head -n 1` command implementation in `cmd` to find the first folder

```dos
dir /b /ad | cmd /e /v /q /c"set/p.=&&echo(^!.^!"
```

This just pipes the output of the `dir` command to a separate `cmd` instance (with delayed expansion and extensions enabled) that will read the first input line and echo it to console.

**note**: Usually this works without problems but in theory there is a possibility so this could fail if the `set /p` is executed exactly while the `dir` is still writing the first line but has not ended, getting a cut line.

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

In CMD you can get the first **non-empy** line of the result of a command by using the [`for /f`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %G IN ('<command>') DO ( echo %G && exit /B 0 )
```

For your example it will be:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %G IN ('dir /b /a-d') DO ( echo %G && exit /B 0 )
```

I don't have a windows machine right away to test it but it should do the trick. Also be aware that the default options make the [`for /f`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) neglect lines beginning with a semicolon `;` (see "*eol*" option in the link).
If you wish to use it in a script, you'll have to use `%%G` instead of `%G` and use a goto

**EDIT**: The `for /f` can also be used to [read files](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) (not intention of the OP but related to the question). Reading the first line is then basicly the same thing (except the input of the `for /f`, it will be `IN (<file>)` instead of `IN ('<command>')`.
If one wishes the first `nlines` lines of a command (again for files, just change the input of the `for /f`) a more complex script will be needed `for /f`:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM for this example, the first 5 lines
set nlines=5
set count=0
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('<command>') DO ( 
    set /a count+=1
    IF !count! GTR %nlines% goto :afterLoop
    echo %%G
)
:afterLoop
EndLocal
```

Here also, the empty lines and those starting with a semicolon (depending on the options of the `for /f`) will be neglected and (not counted) by the `for /f`.

Comment: And here we have the perfect example of scripting. Hence `or other script languages`. It's a primitive one but it would be scripting and IMO it doesn't really qualify as simple either. That doesn't mean it's not a sound solution but with the requirements of the initial question there really isn't much of a solution if there is no standard out of the box command that would implement it.

Answer (score -3):

In Command Line Interface, try using "head" command
Usage:
    head filename

This will display the contents of your file.